# Can I apply Leibniz' integration rule to $\mu(z-z_0)=\int_{z_0}^{z}dz_1~f(z_1-z_0)\int_{z_1}^{z}dz_2~f(z_2-z_1)G(z-z_2)$?

Tags: integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

In modeling a physical phenomenon I have come upon the following integral equation:
\begin{equation}
\mu(z-z_0)=\int_{z_0}^{z}dz_1~f(z_1-z_0)\int_{z_1}^{z}dz_2~f(z_2-z_1)G(z-z_2)
\end{equation}
where $f,G,$ are known functions. My intention was to obtain a differential equation for $\mu$, so after reading [post-1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/663740/leibniz-rule-in-a-double-integral) and [post-2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397992/leibniz-rule-multiple-integrals), I applied the [Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) as follows:
\begin{align}
\frac{d\mu}{dz} & = \frac{d}{dz}\int_{z_0}^{z}dz_1~f(z_1-z_0)\int_{z_1}^{z}dz_2~f(z_2-z_1)G(z-z_2) \\
& =f(z-z_0)\int_{z}^{z}dz_2~f(z_2-z)G(z-z_2)\\
& +\int_{z_0}^{z}dz_1~f(z_1-z_0)~\frac{d}{dz}\int_{z_1}^{z}dz_2~f(z_2-z_1)G(z-z_2) \\
& = 0+\int_{z_0}^{z}dz_1~f(z_1-z_0)~\frac{d}{dz}\int_{z_1}^{z}dz_2~f(z_2-z_1)G(z-z_2) \\
& = \int_{z_0}^{z}dz_1~f(z_1-z_0)\int_{z_1}^{z}dz_2~f(z_2-z_1)\frac{dG(z-z_2) }{dz}
\end{align}

However I am suspicious about this result because it does not make physical sense, because I know for sure that $dG/dz<0, f\geq 0$, but we need $d\mu/dz\geq 0$ (actually $\mu$ is an average collision count and it is supposed to increase with total distance traveled viz. $z-z_0$). So is there something wrong with my derivation above?

Answer (score 0):

why is your first summand $0$ after differentiating? It looks like it should be the following if you are using the product rule to expand first: $$\dfrac{d\mu}{dz} = (f(z-z_0)-f(0))\int_{z_1}^zdz_2f(z_2-z_1)G(z-z_2)+\dfrac{d}{dz}...$$

Comment: I made the replacement $z_1\to z$ in the first summand (as demanded by Leibniz rule, as far as my understanding goes), and then both lower and upper limits on the integral in the first summand become equal, giving zero.

Comment: I am not sure what you are thinking Leibnitz rule is, but the limits of integrations $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ stays the same after taking derivative. Exactly  which part of the Leibnitz rule demands you to make such substitution?

Comment: I have given the link to Wiki article on Leibniz rule in my question.

Comment: @deep you would think I noticed that. If you are not willing to check your work for a simple mistake that I mentioned, then neither am I.

Comment: From that same article that I mentioned: $\frac{d}{dx}\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}dtf(x,t)=f(x,b(x))\frac{db}{dx}-f(x,a(x))\frac{da}{dx}+\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}dt\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial x}$. It is the first two terms that demand substitution.

Comment: there is no integral in the first two terms. or are you not using the product rule to expand first before using the Leibnitz rule? The first two terms must give you zeros because $a(x) =z_0$ and $b(x) = z_1$, so their derivatives with respect to $z$, the variable of your function, is zero.